# iOS In-App purchase for Non-Consumable affected by IPV6

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, ipv6

I implement IAP using Swift to unlock my game stage. It works well on IPv4. So I submit this binary for review and get rejected by Apple when they tested on IPv6 network.

Reject binary reason:

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone running iOS 9.3.2 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.
>   Specifically, after we purchase the In App Purchase, the level does not unlock.

I put break point for every case but the program didn't go inside any 1 of them when I running on IPv6 network.

Here my code for do purchase:

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])    {
    print("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple");

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
            switch trans.transactionState {
            case .Purchased:
                print("Product Purchased");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                self.levelButtonHalloween.enabled = true
                lockImage.removeFromSuperview()
                Overlay.removeFromSuperview()
                userSettingDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "enableHalloween")
                userSettingDefaults.synchronize()
                DesertOver50 = userSettingDefaults.boolForKey("enableHalloween")
                buyBottom.removeFromSuperview()
                backgroundImage.removeFromParent()
                backgroundImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "StageSelect_Background2")
                backgroundImage.size = self.frame.size
                backgroundImage.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)
                backgroundImage.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
                backgroundImage.zPosition = 0
                addChild(backgroundImage)
                break;
            case .Failed:
                print("Purchase Failed");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                break;
            case .Restored:
                print("Transaction restored")
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
                self.levelButtonHalloween.enabled = true
                lockImage.removeFromSuperview()
                Overlay.removeFromSuperview()
                userSettingDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "enableHalloween")
                userSettingDefaults.synchronize()
                DesertOver50 = userSettingDefaults.boolForKey("enableHalloween")
                buyBottom.removeFromSuperview()
                backgroundImage.removeFromParent()
                backgroundImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "StageSelect_Background2")
                backgroundImage.size = self.frame.size
                backgroundImage.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)
                backgroundImage.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
                backgroundImage.zPosition = 0
                addChild(backgroundImage)
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().removeTransactionObserver(self)
}
```

I also implement button for restore purchase and it work well for both ipv4 and ipv6.

Here the code for restore purchase:

```
func restorePurchaseButtonAction(){
    button_Clicked()
    if (DesertOver50 == false){
        if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
            // Enable SKPayment as soon as possible during viewdidload
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
        }
    }else{
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "It's already unlocked ¬_¬", message: "Your have already unlocked or purchased the item(s)", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
        }
        alert.addAction(ok)
        alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
        alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = self.frame
        self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Anyone have experience this before? Any different implement IAP on IPv4 vs IPv6? What should I do next?

Answer (score 1):

Do you check your settings in ItunesConnect whether in-app purchase is registered correctly? Remember to put

> SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)

in viewDidLoad. This issue has been plaguing me too.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your advice. My ituneConnect seem ok.

that `SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)` is root cause
of my problem.

Scenario 1:
Item completely purchase but stage not unlock =>Fail

```
func buyNonConsumable() {
    button_Clicked()
    print("About to fetch the products");
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)      
    // We check that we are allow to make the purchase.
    if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.product_id!);
        let productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>);
        productsRequest.delegate = self;
        productsRequest.start();
        print("Fething Products");
    } else {
        print("can't make purchases");
    }
}
```

Scenario 2: Item auto unlock itself when app start without need to login =>Fail

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {  
// In-App button and function call
    if(DesertOver50 == false) {
        product_id = "xxxxxxxx";
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)     
        addBotton();
```

Scenario 3: Working properly

```
func buyProduct(product: SKProduct) {
    print("Sending the Payment Request to Apple");
    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment);
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
}
```

From what I understand scenario 2 should best solution but it fail.
Since code now working perfectly, I assume scenario 3 is the solution.

Comment: Hey, so did your app got approved? What changes did you make?

Comment: Yes app got approved. Just do as scenario 3.